# How to show an error when wrong input is given

Tags: java

I wrote this code for hiding and unhiding any files or folders but how to show an error when user gives wrong input, I tried using else if but with wrong logic code, I want to show error when ever user gives wrong input while selecting to hide or unhide and if user gives wrong path to hide or unhide files.

```
import java.io.*;
class k
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String a,h;
        boolean q=true;
        while(q==true){
            try{
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                System.out.print("\nunhide/hide/exit (u/h/e): ");
                h=br.readLine();
                if("hide".equalsIgnoreCase(h)){

                    System.out.print("\nwhat you want 2 hide: ");
                    a=br.readLine();


                    if(a.equals(a)){
                        Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
                        Process p=r.exec("cmd.exe /c attrib +h "+a);
                        System.out.print("HIDDEN SUCCESSFULLY");
                    }

                        //else if(!a.equals(a)){System.out.print("error");}
                }else if("unhide".equalsIgnoreCase(h)){
                    System.out.print("what u want to unhide: ");
                    a=br.readLine();
                    if(a.equals(a)){
                        Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
                        Process p=r.exec("cmd.exe /c attrib -h "+a);
                    }
                    System.out.print("UNHIDDEN SUCCESSFULLY");
                }

                else if("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(h)){
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you define "wrong input"

Comment: Also is your commented out else if what you want to work?

Comment: Indent your code for a better world.

Comment: Any problem with throwing validation error messages?

Comment: `if(a.equals(a))` what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @Pshemo Ensure that java hasn't gone mad?

Comment: `if(!a.equals(a))` What? Maybe Java just went mad already...

Comment: Just to explain `if(a.equals(a))` will **always** be true for Strings (any for any object that doesn't have a broken `.equals()` method). Under what circumstances would you expect `a` to not be equal to `a`

Comment: @user2724733 change `if(a.equals(a)){` to `if("<ValidInputHere>".equals(a)){` and just add `else { System.out.print("error"); }`.  `"<ValidInputHere>"` is what you are expecting from the user and `a` is what user provided.

Answer (score 2):

**First:** You make the user choose from 3 letters (`h`, `u`, `e`), 
so you need to sure that the user enter "h" not "hide" , so your check need to be

```
   if ("h".equalsIgnoreCase(h)) //h not hide {
    .....
}
```

**second** : Its easy to check if the path you entered is exist or not , so if it's wrong you can know that , like this :

```
if (new File(a).exists()) {
      Process p = r.exec("cmd.exe /c attrib +h " + a);
      System.out.print("HIDDEN SUCCESSFULLY " + p);

} else {
      System.out.println("wrong input");
}
```

Comment: why h not hide? If we're going down that route; choose from a numbered list

Comment: it's according to the input system (which he tell it to the user), 'unhide/hide/exit (u/h/e)' , look at the choise letters

Comment: You're right, I read that but assigned it as "madness" and moved on

Answer (score 1):

#### Validating option selection

You're 90% of the way there with the first error message, remember if you have a series of `if{} else if{} else if {}else{}` then anything that doesn't fit in the ifs will end up in the else. So

```
if("hide".equalsIgnoreCase(h)){

    System.out.print("\nwhat you want 2 hide: ");
    a=br.readLine();


    if(a.equals(a)){ //<-----a.equals(a) is not valid validation!
        Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p=r.exec("cmd.exe /c attrib +h "+a);
        System.out.print("HIDDEN SUCCESSFULLY");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }

}

}else if("unhide".equalsIgnoreCase(h)){
    System.out.print("what u want to unhide: ");
    a=br.readLine();
    if(a.equals(a)){
        Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p=r.exec("cmd.exe /c attrib -h "+a);
    }
    System.out.print("UNHIDDEN SUCCESSFULLY");
}else if("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(h)){
    System.exit(1);
}else{
    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
}
```

This will give an error message on entering a non valid option, but your existing validation of the file name is not correct so an error message for that cannot be generated without a definition of "incorrect".

#### Path validation

I'm guessing invalid is anything that triggers that catch block so move the try catch inside the loop and use it to validate the input;

```
if("hide".equalsIgnoreCase(h)){

    System.out.print("\nwhat you want 2 hide: ");
    a=br.readLine();


    try{
        Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p=r.exec("cmd.exe /c attrib +h "+a);
        System.out.print("HIDDEN SUCCESSFULLY");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print("Invalid path");
    }

}
```

#### Other points

As discussed in the comments `if(a.equals(a))` will always be false. Whatever `a` *is*, it intrinsically is itself